# How to access the bit at a particular index?

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation

How do I access the bit at a particular index in a number using shift operator.
Say the number is $n$.
Let the index be $i (i: 0 \le i < n).$
Rightmost bit is $0$.

The only thing I can think of is:
$def \, bitAt(n, i)$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,m = n >> i+1$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,v = n >> i$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,m = m << 1$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,if(m == v)$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,return \, 0$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,else$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,return \, 1$
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,end$
$end$

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about efficiency, but this also works:
`if ((n << i) & n) == 0 return 0 else return 1`. What this does is create a number with the `i`th bit set to one, then `AND` this with the original number, if that bit is `1` in the original number, the result is `n << 1`, otherwise it becomes zero.

Comment: Are you sure about it? (n << i) should just set the first i bits to 0. The ith bit is set to the LSB. It's not clear to me how using and on the two will determine the bit that was the LSB? Or the ith bit if that was the aim.

Comment: Ah sorry, there is a typo there, I meant `((1 << i) & n) == 0` in the conditional, `1 << i` sets the `i`th bit to 1.

Comment: Thanks, this would work. Make it an answer (even if it's not more efficient (which I doubt (I think it's more efficient)) It is shorter than my algorithm, which is a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by running an `AND` between `n` and a number with it's `i`th bit set to 1, which can be obtained by `1 << i`. The result of this operation will be zero if the `i`th bit in `n` is zero, or `1 << i` otherwise.

Case of zero:

```
n     = 10111
m     = 01000 (1 << 3)
n & m = 00000
```

Case of one:

```
n     = 10111
m     = 00100 (1 << 2)
n & m = 00100 (1 << 2)
```

So:

$m = 1 << i$

$\text{if}\; (n \;\&\; m == 0)$

$\;\;\;\;\text{return} \;0$

$\text{else}$

$\;\;\;\;\text{return} \;1$